# Can I rewrite an app with android studio which was originally written by app inventor

Tags: android-studio, app-inventor

I published an app in the play store which I am using App Inventor to develop it, can a I rewrite it by android studio and update my App in the play store with the one which I have written with android studio?
in other words can I continue updating my app with a package written with android studio?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same package name and signing the app with the same credentials, yes.

See: [Signing in Release Mode](https://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode) and especially the warning in that section:

> Warning: Keep your keystore and private key in a safe and secure
>   place, and ensure that you have secure backups of them. If you publish
>   an app to Google Play **and then lose the key** with which you signed your
>   app, **you will not be able** to publish any updates to your app, since
>   you **must always sign all versions of your app with the same key**.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the same package name and sign it with the same key it should be fine.